# find common data python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using

```
def compare_lsts(list1,list2):
    first_set = set(list1)
    second_set=set(list2)
    results =[x for x in list1 if x in list2]
    print(results)
```

and running `compare_lsts([1,2,3,4,5],[3,8,9,1,7])` gives the numbers contained in both sets, i.e. `[1,3]`.

However making list 1 contain more than 1 list e.g. `compare_lsts([[1,2,3,4,5],[5,8,2,9,12],[3,7,19,4,16]],[3,7,2,16,19])` gives `[],[],[]`.

I have used for list in list1 followed by results for the loop. I clearly don't know what I am doing.

Basically the question is: How does one compare items in one static list with as many lists as there are?

Comment: What is your expected output for the latter case? Do you just want find all numbers that are in *all* lists, or those numbers from `list2` which are in *any* of `list1`’s sublists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're after elements from the first that are in **all** of the lists:

```
set(first).intersection(second, third) # fourth, fifth, etc...
>>> set([1, 2, 3]).intersection([2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5])
set([3])
```

If you're after elements from the first that are in **any** of the other lists:

```
>>> set([1, 2, 3]) & set([4]).union([5])
set([2])
```

So, then a simple func:

```
def in_all(fst, *rst):
    return set(fst).intersection(*rst)

def in_any(fst, *rst):
    it = iter(rst)
    return set(fst) & set(next(it, [])).union(*it)
```

Comment: OP’s list `[5, 8, 2, 9, 12]` cannot be presented using a string sequence. Not to mention, that you lose the actual data type information anyway…

Comment: @poke What's strings have to do with it? it's easier to type set('123') then it is set([1, 2, 3]) - it's still 3 unique objects for demonstration purposes (and not sure what you mean by data type information) ...

Comment: `set(['2'])` is not the same as `set([2])`, as `'2'` is not the same as `2`. And while it might be easier to type, it is much more confusing because beginners would always understand a string as a single object, and not a sequence of characters, so you are obfuscating relevant information.

Comment: @poke okay - un-deliberate obfuscation removed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you already started using sets, so you should definitely use them, as they are faster when checking containment. Also, there are already a few helpful built-in features for sets, so for comparing two lists, you can just intersect the sets to get those items that are in both lists:

```py
>>> set1 = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> set2 = set([3, 8, 9, 1, 7])
>>> set1 & set2
{1, 3}
>>> list(set1 & set2) # in case you need a list as the output
[1, 3]
```

Similarly, you can also find the union of two sets to get those items that are in any of the sets:

```py
>>> set1 | set2
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}
```

So, if you want to find all items from list2 that are in any of list1’s sublists, then you could intersect all the sublists with list2 and then union all those results:

```py
>>> sublists = [set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), set([5, 8, 2, 9, 12]), set([3, 7, 19, 4, 16])]
>>> otherset = set([3, 7, 2, 16, 19])
>>> intersections = [sublist & otherset for sublist in sublists]
>>> intersections
[{2, 3}, {2}, {16, 3, 19, 7}]
>>> union = set()
>>> for intersection in intersections:
        union = union | intersection
>>> union
{16, 19, 2, 3, 7}
```

You can also do that a little bit nicer using `functools.reduce`:

```py
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(set.union, intersections)
{16, 19, 2, 3, 7}
```

Similarly, if you want to actually intersect those results, you could do that as well:

```py
>>> functools.reduce(set.intersection, intersections)
set()
```

And finally, you can pack that all in a nice function:

```py
def compareLists (mainList, *otherLists):
    mainSet = set(mainList)
    otherSets = [set(otherList) for otherList in otherLists]

    intersections = [mainSet & otherSet for otherSet in otherSets]
    return functools.reduce(set.union, intersections) # or replace with set.intersection
```

And use it like this:

```py
>>> compareLists([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 8, 9, 1, 7])
{1, 3}
>>> compareLists([3, 7, 2, 16, 19], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 8, 2, 9, 12], [3, 7, 19, 4, 16])
{16, 19, 2, 3, 7}
```

Note, that I replaced the order of the arguments in the function, so the main list (in your case *list2*) is mentioned first as that is the one the others are compared to.

Comment: wow! Thank you very much. I shall work through this to understand the syntax properly

Comment: When I use the comparison of multiple sets as written above, I get 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'set'' Have I done something stupid again?

Comment: Then you didn’t make a set first; both operands of `&` need to be sets. You can convert your list by doing `set(lst)`.

Comment: Stupid boy that I am! Left out a square bracket in the definition of sublists. Works now as it always would have, had I not ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way but:

```
def flat(l):
    c_l = []
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            map(c_l.append,i)
        else:
            c_l.append(i)
    return c_l


def compare_lsts(a,b):
    if all([True if isinstance(x,list) else False for x in a]): #if there is sublists in a
        a = flat(a) #flats a

    if all([True if isinstance(x,list) else False for x in b]): #if there is sublists in b
        b = flat(b) #flats b


    return list(set(a) & set(b)) #intersection between a and b


print (compare_lsts([[1,2,3,4,5],[5,8,2,9,12],[3,7,19,4,16]],[3,7,2,16,19]) #[16, 3, 2, 19, 7])
```

Comment: I get returned from this [],[],[] Clearly there is something that I am not doing correctly although I believe that I have retyped it exactly as above and used Python Visualisor